# Combine arrays in a loop cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I'm working on an import for my customers and this is working in loops of 100 as a test. In each loop I can save the array of that customer, but I think its faster to combine the arrays from each loop and save them all at the end when 100 is reached.The data comes from a csv file.

The fist thing I want to know what is better, saving each loop seperatly or at the end all at once?

The arry I'm creating is as follow:

```
//Process file
        if (($handle = fopen('uploads/temp/'.$file, "r")) !== FALSE)
        while (  (($dop_ar = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) && (($_POST['start_id']+1)*100 >= $counter) ) {

            if ($_POST['start_id']*100 <= $counter) {

                $data_customer = array(
                        "Customer" => array (
                            "id" => $dop_ar[0],
                            "factuurvoornaam" => $dop_ar[12],
                            "factuurachternaam" => $dop_ar[14]
                            ),  
                );

                $this->Customer->create();
                if ($this->Customer->save($data_customer)) {
                // handle the success.
                //echo 'ok';
                }

            }

            $counter++;
        }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to combine the arrays while I'm in the loop so that I can use saveall at the end of the loop when 100 is reached. If I'm right I must use an index so cakephp know that he has to insert more than one customer.

Hopefully somebody can help me to get in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 0):

To save many records at once, just add them to the model data array as numeric elements of the model alias. So your data would look like:

```
$dataToSave = array(
    'Customer' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 54,
            'factuurvoornaam' => 'Test',
            'factuurachternaam' => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 456,
            'factuurvoornaam' => 'Test',
            'factuurachternaam' => '2'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 92,
            'factuurvoornaam' => 'Test',
            'factuurachternaam' => '3'
        )
    )
);
```

Try this:

```
$customers = array();

if ($handle = fopen('uploads/temp/' . $file, 'r')) {

    while ($dop_ar = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ';')) && (($_POST['start_id'] + 1) * 100 >= $counter)) {

        if ($_POST['start_id'] * 100 <= $counter) {

            $customers['Customer'][] = array(
                'id' => $dop_ar[0],
                'factuurvoornaam' => $dop_ar[12],
                'factuurachternaam' => $dop_ar[14]
            );
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}

if (!empty($customers)) {
    $this->Customer->saveAll($customers);
}
```

Comment: BadHorsie this is working with a small change. I had to change the following: $customers['Customer'][] to $customers[] otherwise cakephp did only a rollback, not sure why. When inserting cakephp checks every id with a count, wich slows down the progress. I use $this->Customer->begin(); and $this->Customer->commit(); now, but this isn't a big speedup. Do you have any suggestions to improve the speed of the insert of the data?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't test just wrote it. I don't know what to suggest for the speed, I guess that is just the issue with performing so many inserts in a loop.